# Posting code that violates Google's TOS

Tags: discussion, legal

For a quick project, I thought it would be cool to make a crawler that goes over Google results, finding and recording sites that are scraping and impersonating Stack Exchange sites.

The problem is, as far as I know, such a program would violate Google's TOS. They cut support for their API, and I sure wouldn't pay for a service just for a quick side project, so I would be doing manual scraping.

Would there be any issue with posting the code for review?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Writing (and sharing) the code is not something that can be a problem. Actually running the code and accessing the API's is where the issue becomes problematic.

This is true for many types of coding projects, especially security-related, or educational projects.

In short, the question would be fine, but a warning to the reader indicating that they should exercise caution when running the code would probably be a good idea.

This question is similar to: [How well is "malicious" code accepted here?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1517/how-well-is-malicious-code-accepted-here)