# Is hacking/cracking on-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope

[Login to website behind captcha](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/229351) seeks to circumvent a captcha. I think that white-hat hacking or penetration testing for the purpose of security improvement might be OK, but this is clearly in the opposite category: exploitation for its own sake. Is this on-topic? Is it OK to be teaching people how to circumvent security, anti-tamper or anti-abuse systems such as captchas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cracking/Hacking is not a reason for a post to be off-topic, but this specific question has incomplete, and non-functional code, so it's not working as intended, so it is off-topic.

I have closed it with that reason.

Having said that, if/when the code works, it would possibly be ready to reopen as working code.

There is a question answered about these types of questions before in Meta... [Here](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1517/31503)

Comment: Thanks - I voted to close this as a dupe.